# Search for sound tags in the audio signal

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, soundfile

I have an audio recording that was recorded through a telephone channel, the beginning and end of which contain an audio tag. I have a "clean" version of this audio signal, its spectrogram looks like this:

[image: "clean" version of audio tag]

The spectrogram of the sound recording looks like this:
[image: example of spectrogram of recording]

Note: the length of this audio tag is exactly 1 second

How can I find all occurrences of this tag in the audio file? There can be 30-50 such audio tags in this audio file. The mask search will not work, since it is obvious that the sound that passed through the telephone channel has some distortion.
In theory, I would like to get all the sample indexes that this audio tag starts with, then I would be able to trim them knowing the length of the audio tag and the samplerate of the audio file (samplerate may vary)

Comment: So what is it you are looking for? Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any developments. Don't get me wrong, I'm not asking the community to do this for me, I just don't know which direction to go, so I'm asking for advice. Perhaps there are some developments that I could not find

Comment: Could you explain why you think (or even know) that "the mask search will not work"? You have the "mask" of the sound tag, and it looks pretty recognizable in the spectrogram of the recording. If you mean that it will never be **exactly** the same, I agree. What you could do is to define a *distance* metrics, set a threshold corresponding to te detection of an actual sound tag, and select below-threshold minima of this distance function as detected tags.

Comment: Correlation in time domain, correlation in stft domain, machine learning approaches

Comment: Can you provide a link to a downloadable audio file with these sounds in it, and notes at which times it occurs? Then it would be possible to provide an reproducible answer